# CSS "position:fixed" scroll text overlapping issue

Tags: html, css

How to avoid overlapping header text in this case?
And why overflow hidden for sections above and visible for sections under?

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/sftrq1hv/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section.hero {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

section.hero h1 {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
}

section :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.bg1 {
  background: yellow;
}

.bg2 {
  background: cyan;
}

.bg3 {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="hero bg1">
    <h1 class="hero-title">0</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="hero bg2">
    <h1 class="hero-title">1</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="hero bg3">
    <h1 class="hero-title">2</h1>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a `clip-path` or `mask` to hide `position:fixed`. overflow won't work with `position:fixed`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section.hero {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
  /*OR
   -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
           mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  */
}

section.hero h1 {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
}

section :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.bg1 {
  background: yellow;
}

.bg2 {
  background: cyan;
}

.bg3 {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero bg1">
  <h1 class="hero-title">0</h1>
</section>
<section class="hero bg2">
  <h1 class="hero-title">1</h1>
</section>
<section class="hero bg3">
  <h1 class="hero-title">2</h1>
</section>
```